# Start a thread as soon as a long post request comes in

Tags: servlets, grails, http-post

I am trying to upload an image. I need to start a synchronising thread as soon as the http request comes in. Presently my Grails code starts only after the entire post data has been received.

Answer (score 0):

The controller is in fact invoked as soon as the request comes in. Only when the image data is fetched from the http request body does the code stall and wait for the upload to finish.